# Include select value first in option "select."

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, html-select

Select first I want the value to come. how can I do it?

````
                $.each(data.departmentList, function (key, value) {
                    $('#searchDepartmentName')
                        .append($("<option></option>")
                            .attr("value", value.mudurlukId)
                            .text(value.mudurlukAdi));
                });
               
                $('#searchDepartmentName').append(optionData);
            },  ```
````

Answer (score 0):

you can set the selected attribute accordingly.

```js
const data = {
  departmentList: [
    {mudurlukId: "1", mudurlukAdi: "test1"},
    {mudurlukId: "2", mudurlukAdi: "test2"}
  ]
};

$('#searchDepartmentName').html(data.departmentList.map((v, i) => {
    const selected = i === 0 ? " selected" : "";
  return `<option ${selected} value=${v.mudurlukId}>${v.mudurlukAdi}</option>`;
}));
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="searchDepartmentName">
</select>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will set the first option to be selected:

```
$.each(data.departmentList, function (key, value) {
  const select = $('#searchDepartmentName');
  const elem = $("<option></option>")
    .attr("value", value.mudurlukId)
    .text(value.mudurlukAdi);
  
  select.append(elem)
  
  if (elem.is(":first-child")) {
    select.val(value.mudurlukId);
  }
});
```